# Delete multiple objects at once using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to delete a bunch of objects with one query using the `CriteriaBuilder` API. I'm looking for something like this select:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
Root<T> root = query.from(entityClass);
query.select(root).where(/*some condition*/);
return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

but then a delete instead of a select. As far as I can see, there's no `remove` or `delete` method on `CriteriaQuery`. Is it possible using this API?

I can of course execute the select, then call `entityManager.remove(object)` for each result, but that feels very inefficient.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder  = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaDelete<SomeClass> query = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaDelete(SomeClass.class);
Root<SomeClass> root = query.from(SomeClass.class);
query.where(root.get("id").in(listWithIds));

int result = entityManager.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

The where clause can laso look like this:

```
query.where(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("id"), someId));
```

Comment: the `createCriteriaDelete` method does not exist in my library. In which version was it added?

Comment: Just upgraded to Hibernate 4.3 (from 4.2), and it's there now. Thanks!

Comment: createCriteriaDelete was added with JPA2.1 - as Cruis said

Answer (score 9):

in JPA 2.1, there are Criteria APIs exactly as what you want.it looks like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaDelete<T> cq = cBuilder.createCriteriaDelete(entityClass);
Root<T> root = cq.from(entityClass);
cq.where(/*some codition*/);
int result = em.createQuery(cq).executeUpdate();
```

you can refert to JPA 2.1 SPEC and API [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-pr-spec/index.html)

Comment: Plus one for the documentation link